# Create application session in android

Tags: java, android, coding-style, event-handling

My application require timeout of 10 min i.e. if there is no activity on the application from last 10 min, then either the application is terminated or login(Login credential in sqlite db) is shown.

I came up with the approach of using thread with maintain perform the task but that approach is untidy approach.

Suggest me some better approach.

Comment: After reading your comments I think you already know that its not possible using without threads

Answer (score 2):

I would do this way.

1. Save the current time (in millisec) to pref file in `onPause();`
2. Retrieve the time from pref file and compare with current time in `onResume();`
3. If the time difference is more than 10, just `finish()` the activity and ask for log in.

Answer (score 1):

Use timer class to do this task / alternatively can use Alarm class for the same.
Depends on requirement.
Thread will certainly not be a good option.

Comment: Task would indirecty be a thread(though save threading approach) and alarm will be battery-consuming approach.

Answer (score 0):

You may use AsyncTask to do this job.

Comment: AsyncTask is android approach of thread. I am trying not to use thread